# Use external jars in EJB (JBoss)

Tags: jboss, jakarta-ee, ejb

I want to use two external jars from EJB:

1. jar #1 - all interfaces of the EJB (home, remote etc)
2. jar #2 - some types which I use inside my EJB

What should I do to achieve this? If I put this jars inside ear it doesn't work, and JBoss throws `NoClassFoundException`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to include them in a lib directory under the ear:

```
 yourapp.ear
   ->lib
       ->jar1.jar
       ->jar2.jar
```

Comment: Stil not working :( Maybe it's important that I'm using and old JBoss version 3.2.1 (cannot change it). Do I need to add sth in deployment descriptors or somewhere else?

Comment: I had to add Class-Path element in manifest and than it didn't matter where jars were.

Comment: @Filip, yes that mattered. I assumed you were using EJB3. For EJB2 the Class-Path element is the solution.